# Why am I getting wildly incorrect results from FirstPassageTimeDistribution with inexact transition matrix?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy, markov-chains

Working on some large systems using `DiscreteMarkovProcess`, I changed the transition matrix to machine precision vs using exact values, which sped things up handily. The only problem was for edge cases, accuracy suffered. I expected that. However, when probing the limits using simple cases, I was surprised to find this happens when I'd not expected it.

A simplified test example:

```
Table[
 intleg = tleg/2;

 sa = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 
     1 - (intleg - i + 1)/tleg, {i_, j_} /; 
      j == i + 1 :> (1 - i + intleg)/tleg}, {intleg + 1, intleg + 1}];


 saN = N[sa, 50];

 mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, sa];
 mpN = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, saN];

 {tleg, N@Mean[FirstPassageTimeDistribution[mp, intleg + 1]],
  N@Mean[FirstPassageTimeDistribution[mpN, intleg + 1]]},

 {tleg, {10, 20, 30, 40}}]

(* {{10,22.8333,22.8333},{20,58.5794,58.5793},{30,99.5469,-1.24192},{40,143.91,0.}} *)
```

This simulates a simple "coupon-collector" situation with a population of `tleg` distinct items, where only half are "interesting" to me. So a transition matrix is built with appropriate probabilities with an absorbing state when all "interesting" are obtained. That same matrix is converted to inexact via `N`.

Comparing the results, we see the last two are not even in the zip-code of the correct result. Upping the accuracy/precision of the conversion via `N` seems to have no effect.

Any ideas what's going on here (I suspect some kind of catastrophic cancellation because of the characteristics of the probabilities)?

Comment: I really don't know. It looks like it could be a bug rather than a numerical problem, as the `Precision` of the results doesn't decrease very much with respect to the input. But possibly this is just a case that is handled very badly by significance arithmetic. I suspect we need @AndyRoss to tell us what's really going on here?

Comment: This one wasn't my baby so I can't really say for sure what is going on.  I suspect that a completely different algorithm is being used for inexact numbers and it is failing. You should file a bug.

Comment: @AndyRoss: I shall do so, however I'll wait a bit to see and responses and if perhaps there's something I missed... Thanks for reply.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Thanks for reply - yes, it *is* a strange one, I'm still poking at it, but see AndyRoss' reply...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the report, @rasher. This was a bug and it is already fixed in the development version.

```
In[1]:= Table[intleg = tleg/2;
 sa = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 
     1 - (intleg - i + 1)/tleg, {i_, j_} /; 
      j == i + 1 :> (1 - i + intleg)/tleg}, {intleg + 1, intleg + 1}];
 saN = N[sa, 50];
 mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, sa];
 mpN = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, saN];
 {tleg, N@Mean[FirstPassageTimeDistribution[mp, intleg + 1]], 
  N@Mean[FirstPassageTimeDistribution[mpN, intleg + 1]]}, {tleg, {10, 20, 30, 40}}]

Out[1]= {{10, 22.8333, 22.8333}, {20, 58.5794, 58.5794}, {30, 99.5469, 99.5469}, {40, 143.91, 143.91}}
```

Unfortunately I don't have a workaround at the moment. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation (Are you WRI staff?). Glad to hear it's fixed in upcoming release.

Comment: Yes, I worked on the Markov process functionality.

Comment: Cool! Thanks again for response, I'll go ahead and add bug tag.